# iOS Save Text from Dynamic TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am building a part of my app that uses a Dynamic TableView with a UITableViewCell class with 1 label and two UITextFields. One textfield is for the user to type a question and the other is for them to type an answer. The goal is to save the text from the two text fields into CoreData. I am however unsure how to correctly identify one textfield from another since there may be 4 or 5 rows with the same text fields in the table.

I've attached a screen shot of what it looks like.

[image: Screenshot of tableview]

Should I be using tags on each textfield? If so, how can I set that up?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can use the subviews of the UITableViewCell's contentView to get the UITextFields. You know which row/cell you have so this will give you the textfields that go with them. (E.g. cell at indexPath.row will have first UITextField at subview 0, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your exact setup, but it seems easiest to use tags.

When you set the placeholder text for each "He said/I said," also add a line `textField.tag = <uniqueTag>` where you (arbitrarily) come up with a unique tag for each `UITextField` that you have. Then, when the user hits save, or when you get a call to a delegate method for all of these text fields, you can differentiate them by checking their `tag` property.